# iOS - Play ringing sound when "called" in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, swift

I was wondering if it was possible to play a continues sound in my Skype like application when a user is called an the other user has the app installed but the app is in the background in the moment.

It would be really awesome if it could could show an "accept / decline" on the lock screen. But that might not be possible is it?

I have looked around on the internet, but I could not find it. (I think I saw something related to this on a keynote once, but that might just be my memory hoping it exists.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is possible to show an "accept / decline" on lock screen or notification itself. The only thing that is not possible to do is to make input field for quick response (as it's done in Messages app)
[image]

There is [nice guide](https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8) to interactive notifications for iOS8.

To play sound i suggest you to use possibilities provided by UILocalNotification instead of implementing custom sound/vibration.

Also, if your app is in background, it must use push notifications, so for VoIP apps i suggest you to take a look into [PuskKit framework and special type of pushes - VoIP pushes](https://github.com/sinch/ios-pushkit-tutorial)